# jquery great-great grand parents

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

This identifies to the entire table.

```
var thisOption = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

Is there an easier way to climb up the DOM tree to find the table when I am deep in a  element?

Comment: Do you know the great-great-grandparent's type?

Comment: would work except the table can occur up to 99 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the .closest() method.  For example:

```
$(this).closest("table")
```

This will return the first ancestor "table" element in the DOM tree.

Comment: that is what I was looking for. I skipped "closest" because it sounded like a child-relatinship selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
var thisOption = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

to:

```
var thisOption = $(this).ancestors().eq(6);
```

Comment: nice, this is probably faster, but closest looks more versitile.